# Why I am getting "Notebook out of memory" error upon notebook submission in Kaggle

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, kaggle, large-language-model

I am participating in a Kaggle competition. Over the past 7-10 days I have been facing a peculiar problem. I am trying to make my submission to the competition, but am getting "Notebook out of memory" error again and again as you can see in the picture.

I have tried a variety of things to get rid of the problem, like keeping bare minimum package installations & imports, deleting variables at various junctures and using garbage collection using gc.collect() and even reducing my training dataset to just 50 records. Nothing is working. I am running a simple, straightforward model using "facebook-wav2vec2largexlsr53".

Apart from this model as a dataset, I am installing "Jiwer package with Rapidfuzz" (see the bottom pic). When I SAVEALL or just RUN ALL the notebook, the kernel runs perfectly even with 10000 records and I get the result as expected, but the problem is only for submission (on pressing the SUBMIT button either from output or from the right panel of notebook). By the way I was able to make a submission around 2 weeks back.

What am I doing wrong? How do get rid of this problem and make a submission? This has already caused enormous wastage of time and even Kaggle's valuable platform resources. If I am not doing anything wrong and the problem is with Kaggle platform, how do I take it to their attention? Appreciate inputs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the ram size on your notebook. The model itself is at least 2.5 GB in bin files so when read into memory ND processed you might be running out of memory as the notebook said depending on what kind of virtual machine it's running. You should be able to easily check its available resources but I can't see from the picture you uploaded.

Comment: @Jesse Sealand, when I run the notebook, I see I have 13GB of RAM available and it runs fine. Only when I submit is the problem (here, I will not be knowing the RAM capacity as it is run in the background and would not show)

Comment: By the way the same problem pops up even when I try the base version, 'facebook-wav2vec2-base'